# extend the array-class (note 'array' is in its singular form. I don't mean the Arrays.java )

Tags: java, arrays

If I declare x like this `int[] x`, then `x` is an object, isn't it? Which means `int[]` is a class?

Can I extend that class (for various reasons)?
I tried

```
class Foo extends int[]
{
}
```

But that's not working. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: `int` is a primitive, `Integer` is a class

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend arrays in Java. They're these strange pseudo-class things that act somewhat similar to objects (have methods/fields, etc.) but aren't really. If you're trying to make a custom array, have you looked at the Collections API? That includes things like ArrayLists (arrays with variable lengths), which are pretty useful.

EDIT: If you need an array, use the "toArray()" method that all Collections have.

Comment: I want to extend the `array` because some API that I am using require an array to work with, which means I have to pre-computed the array only in order to pass it to the API's method. But I don't want to do that.... Thought I could build some kind of lazy-evaluation array

Comment: All Collections have a "toArray()" method, so you can still use that API.

Comment: But that still means copying all the items into the newly constructed array, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You can not extend int[] or any other array in Java. It is object but it isn't something you can extend like normal class in java.

int is primitive and you create array of ints using int[]

JComponent is class and you create array of JComponents using JComponent[]

You can extend JComponent class or any other non final class and create arrays of those by just adding [] to the end of variable declaration.

```
class Foobar { .... }

Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
Foobar[] foobarArray = new Foobar[10]; // size 10

class BiggerFoobar extends Foobar {...}

BiggerFoobar[] biggerFoobarArray = new BiggerFoobar[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

An `int[]` is actually an array. It's not an object per se but a variable capable of holding many values of the same type and allowing quick access to them based on an index.

Funny tough, Oracle's documentation describes an array (located under the *Variables* category) as:

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed. You've seen an example of arrays already, in the main method of the "Hello World!" application. This section discusses arrays in greater detail.

`int[]` it's not an actual class type so you have no means of extending it. If you trully need to do this, you can extend any of the objects implementing the `List` interface (`ArrayList` for example) or that you implement the `List` interface yourself with a custom object.

If you want to turn a collection into an array, try something like this:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//Operate with your list
Integer[] arr = intList.toArray(new Integer[intList.size()]);
```

Answer (score -1):

An int is a data type not an object.
Integer is an object, however you cannot extend that either because it is final.

I think you maybe need to re-think what exactly it is you are trying to do it, there is probably a different way.

Comment: He's trying to extend 'int[]', not 'int'.